# Combining steps

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

Is there any way to combine these steps so that I can improve the efficiency by reducing the number of iterations.

```
first_cut_new=first_cut-res
first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>min_value+150]=0
first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>0]=1
first_cut_depth_3D=np.dstack((first_cut_depth,first_cut_depth,first_cut_depth))
first_cut_final= first_cut_depth_3D * first_cut_new
```

Comment: What are the shapes of the inputs involved?

Comment: first_cut -(600,600,3); res-(600,600,3); depth(600,600)

Comment: Can you share your code? Upto what you have done.

Comment: first_cut and res are basically 600 by 600 RGB images where as depth is the depth matrix for the image from a 3D sensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

To me the inefficiency looks like to be at the last two steps. So, one could avoid creating `first_cut_depth_3D` and get to `first_cut_final` with on the fly data replication and elementwise multiplication with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
first_cut_new = first_cut-res
first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>min_value+150]=0
first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>0]=1
first_cut_final = first_cut_depth[...,None]*first_cut_new
```

---

**Approach #2 (for RGB input arrays)**

If `first_cut_depth` is supposed to be a RGB image data, it would only have positive values. So, one can exploit that for a much more efficient one-liner solution, like so -

```
first_cut_final = (first_cut_depth <= min_value+150)[...,None]*(first_cut-res)
```

Comment: how about these two steps     first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>min_value+150]=0
first_cut_depth[first_cut_depth>0]=1

Comment: @user4543816 I would keep those. Those don't look like to be the bottleneck to me.

Comment: @user4543816 Check out the just added second approach too!

Comment: Just to clarify first_cut _depth  is depth data not RGB data. first_cut is rgb data

Comment: @user4543816 Could `first_cut_depth` be negative? If not, then the second approach would work. `first_cut_depth` just needs to be positive, doesn't have to be RGB.